# ROPC - Getting "invalid_grant" error with description as "AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password"

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

```
POST /{{AAD}}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 611fa720-e1f4-5bbc-e0f7-b7620bab24af

client_id={{client_id}}
&username=username@domain.com
&password={{password}}
&grant_type=password
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsot.com%2FMail.Read
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1234
```

For the above request I'm getting response like,

```
"error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: a0bd31e0-59e3-4836-b654-8e449d491c00\r\nCorrelation ID: de329d02-e714-48bb-a876-387167034ba3\r\nTimestamp: 2019-03-05 11:12:51Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50126
    ]
```

I'm using the same password to login the org mail. But still I'm receiving this error. And I can see the username is available in the directory. Delegated Permissions are also granted. Could someone explain what am i missing?

Anything below the reason for this error?

1. I have created the application in my personal outlook account using 
   https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and I'm trying to read the org mail.
2. Our org  is using single sign on

Comment: If you have any more query regarding this feel free to write here in this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the exact sample how you can get token using **Resource Owner Password Credentials** (ROPC)

**Step 1 :**

Set your request URL like this:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/**YourTenantName/TenantID**.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

See the screen shot

[image]

You can Get your tenant name right top of your azure portal. Have a look on the

screen shot below:

[image]

**Step 2 :**

Request header format

[image]

**Step 3 :**

Set your request body as per your application information in following format:

**client_id:** Your Client ID

**client_secret:** Your Application Secret

**username:** Your User Name for this application

**password:** Your Password for this application

**grant_type:** password

**scope:https:**//graph.microsoft.com/.default  Or Your Preferred Scope

*See the screen shot below for request body format:*

[image]

In response I got my token as expected. See the picture below:

[image]

**Possible reason for your problem**:

1. Personal account can not be used for this code flow
2. It might happen if you have changed your application secret and tried with the old one.
3. Your user name and password may not similar with current tenant.

You can try this above example to get your request as expected. You can also check azure portal to check your application is created successfully. for more information you can have a look on
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

**Note:** You are using personal account which is not correct for this flow. see the screen shot below: For details you can see Microsoft Official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried the username as username@org_domain.onmicrosoft.com and I get `AADSTS50034: The user account Microsoft.AzureAD.Telemetry.Diagnostics.PII does not exist in the {{AAD}} directory` , So I have used username@orgdomain.com. And I have set new app secret and password and tried with new credentials. Still facing the issue.

Comment: Fyi I am using the qualified username from the azure directory Users list only

Comment: @Ray I have updated the answer you can try it now. You  can not use personal account for this code flow. Thanks