# Microsoft Oaut2 token returns bad request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I have an issue using Microsoft OAuth2 Token...
By reading the part of the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)
We have this information

```
    // Line breaks and spaces are for legibility only.  This is a public client, so no secret is required.

POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

I came with this code :

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(_uri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>[5]
                {
                    new("client_id", _clientId),
                    new("scope", _scopes),
                    new("username", _userName),
                    new("password", _password),
                    new("grant_type", grant_type)
                }));
```

where the variables are :

_uri is : [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B0%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

_clientId is the id of my azure client (for example : 66c1a416-5fb7-4265-a774-90759e42b0c0)

_tenantId is the id of my azure tenant (for example : 0bbd3fab-1170-40ae-9713-842b3b2b9374)

_scopes are : IMAP.AccessAsUser.All user.read openid profile offline_access

_username is my professional account

_password is the password of my professional account

After executing the code, the result is always BadRequest.

And I don't know why

Kinds for help

Comment: The short-and-quick answer is that when using OAuth2 (and OIDC) you **should not** use ROPC _at all_ (because no-one should be passing user-secrets (i.e. passwords) around like that). Please explain why you're using a password here instead of a user browser-based flow for authX. [This is mentioned in the very article you linked to, in a big yellow box at the top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#:~:text=Microsoft%20recommends%20you%20do%20not%20use%20the%20ROPC%20flow).

Comment: You say you get a _HTTP 400 Bad Request_ response, right? If so, then what is in the response body? It should contain a human-readable error message.

Comment: I will explain the flow :
The client wanted to have a react frontend and .net backend.
In the backend, we need to have an access token to connect to aspose email for our professional microsoft account (MFA activated)
On the front end (I'm not a react expert),  the developer doesn't know how to use MSAL to get an access token (because the tutorials he found don't use React front end with .NET backend) and send it to me, that I can use it for aspose.email.
So to help him, I tried the microsoft article above, but this doesn't work when MFA is activated - I jsut see that fact

Comment: Please post the entire response body of the HTTP 400 Bad Request you get. It should contain either `invalid_grant`, `invalid_request`, `consent_required`, or another OAuth2 error code.

Comment: Could you please share which `grant_type` you are using? and are you getting bad request in  your backend, I mean, the API response from azure?

Answer (score 0):

> After executing the code, the result is always BadRequest.
>
> And I don't know why

Well, based your shared code snippet and description along with official document, it seems you are trying to get access token using [`ROPC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) authentication protocol.

Make sure, you are using tenant created user name as a member type user, not personal account which is not supported for ROPC protocal.

[image]

I have in following way and getting the access token as expected

Token Class:

```cs
 public class AccessTokenClass
        {
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }

        }
```

Method I have used:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetTokenByROPCFormat()
        {

            string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0//token";

            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "password",
                ["client_id"] = "5188529_YourAppID_ba9c7f5f9",
                ["client_secret"] = "uNG8Q~8XROj_YourAPPSecret_onXnTrXycu5",
                ["scope"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
                ["username"] = "tenentspecificID@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                ["password"] = "Password@"

            });

            dynamic json;
            dynamic results;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

            json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Your Refresh Token=>{0}", results.access_token);
        }
```

Pemission:

Make sure, you have required permission on azure portal, I have tested with Microsoft Graph Default permission with admin consent.

[image]

Ouput:

[image]

[image]

> **Note:** Please be informed about following Points which [@Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) already mentioned:

[image]

**Client credentials flow:**

In that case you can implement `Client credential grant flow`: You can get full code snippet for this authentication flow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353142/how-to-generate-azure-active-directory-aad-authentication-token-for-graph-api/56355088#56355088)

**Note:** If you want to see, how to configure permission in azure portal, please [refer to this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004036/ropc-getting-invalid-grant-error-with-description-as-aadsts50126-invalid-u/55009496#55009496)